# Chrome Middle Click Tab Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to write a Google Chrome extension to allow the user to middle click any "blank space" on the top of the window and open a new tab. In other words, I want to switch to Chrome but I like Firefox's behavior.

I am not familiar with how JSON interfaces with Chrome, so would I have to do this using a URL or is there a way to access Chrome's actions?

Answer (score 4):

This isn't possible. Sorry.

Chrome extensions are considerably more limited than Firefox extensions — they can only hook the behavior of the browser in certain predefined ways. They cannot modify core elements of the browser's core user interface, such as the tab bar.

For an overview of what Chrome extensions *can* do, see: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview